# Upgrades to a computer system for the disabled

Tags: compatibility, assistive-technology

My wife has no use of her upper limbs but is a very keen computing enthusiast, like myself. Recently she celebrated her 25th birthday and I bought her a brand new computer knowing how much she loves to make use of technology.

Unfortunately, I don't know what devices or hardware components are available to help my wife use the computer. I have not thought about how she will make use of her new computer considering her disabilities and I am hoping someone can suggest possible upgrades to ensure that she can make the most of he present.

I would like suggestions based on human interaction devices.

Comment: I'd suggest a few improvements - maybe focus this question on human interface devices and focus on what she *can* use as seperate questions.